# Motion Slider works in expo v32 but not in v27 - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have two snacks which have a motion slider, (in Android) the first one works perfectly(this is using version 32 expo) and second one is using version 27:

```
https://snack.expo.io/@drc83/motionsider-v32
```

and

```
https://snack.expo.io/@drc83/motionsider-v27
```

Basically in version 27 there is some clipping of the slider when in use does anyone know what is causing this as I have the same problem (I am not using expo) so wanted to address this to get it working properly.